# Update all records with flask migration script

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm working with a MySQL database in Flask and I need to update the model. I have the migration ready to create the new table column and a script which updates the new column with the *current* primary key. The row is then reinserted with a *new* primary key.

Is there a way to combine the reassignment script with the `migrate` command? Or is it better to run manually after the model has been updated?

**model.py**

```
class Outcome(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    outcome_id = db.Column(db.Integer) # the new property, should match id
    title = db.Column(db.String(64))
    course_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    assignment_id = db.relationship('Assignment', uselist=False, back_populates='outcome')
```

**migration.py**

```
from app import db
from app.models import Outcome
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import make_transient

outcomes = Outcome.query.all()

for outcome in outcomes:
    db.session.expunge(outcome) # use only the object
    make_transient(outcome)

    outcome.outcome_id = outcome.id #add the new column value
    outcome.id = None #set the ID to none to inherit a sequential ID 

    db.session.add(outcome)

db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a matter of preference, it really depends on what works best for your workflow.

You can include it in your Flask-Migrate migration, but keep in mind that using models inside migration scripts is in general not a good idea because you have no way to ensure that the models will remain compatible with the migration as your project evolves. Typically you'd want to use a raw SQL statement if you do this change in the migration script.